# Preserve Formatting When Setting New Cell Value (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following script which sets a new value for a selected spreadsheet cell. It works as expected but **after every entry it clears all the previous formatting from the cell**. How can I modify the code to make sure it **preserves all the partial formatting, such as font weight/color?** Thank you for your help.

```
function enterName1(options1, activity1, number1) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd.MM.yy' at 'HH:mm");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  
  if (value === '') {
      value = value + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
      sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
      cell.setValue(value);
  } else {
      value = value + "\n\n" + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
      sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
      cell.setValue(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Question 1: You want to preserve the existing text styles of the text in the cell when the value is added to the cell including the values.
- Question 2: You want to preserve the existing text styles of the text in the cell when the value is added to the cell including the values. And also, you want to set the text style for `formattedDate` of the adding text.- Question 3: You want to preserve the existing text styles of the text in the cell when the value is added to the cell including the values. And also, you want to set the text style for `formattedDate` of the adding text. And also, even when the cell is empty, you want to set the text style for `formattedDate` of the adding text.

### Answer for question 1:

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to retrieve the text styles of the existing values and set the text styles after the value was added. "RichTextValue" is used for this.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
} else {
    value = value + "\n\n" + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
    sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
    cell.setValue(value);
}
```

To:

```
} else {
  value = value + "\n\n" + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var existingStyles = richTextValue.getRuns().map(e => ({start: e.getStartIndex(), end: e.getEndIndex(), style: e.getTextStyle()}));
  var richTexts = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value);
  existingStyles.forEach(e => richTexts.setTextStyle(e.start, e.end, e.style));
  cell.setRichTextValue(richTexts.build());
  cell.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
}
```

- In this modified script, the text styles of the existing value are set. So the added text has no text style. Please be careful this.

### Answer for question 2:

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to retrieve the text styles of the existing values and also set the text style for `formattedDate`, and then, set the text styles after the value was added. "RichTextValue" is also used for this.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
} else {
    value = value + "\n\n" + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
    sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
    cell.setValue(value);
}
```

To:

```
} else {
  var textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor("#FF0000").build();  // Please set this for the additional text.
  
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var existingStyles = richTextValue.getRuns().map(e => ({start: e.getStartIndex(), end: e.getEndIndex(), style: e.getTextStyle()}));
  var startOffset = (value + "\n\n" + " ").length;
  existingStyles.push({start: startOffset, end: startOffset + formattedDate.length, style: textStyle});
  var richTexts = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value + "\n\n" + "到 " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1);
  existingStyles.forEach(e => richTexts.setTextStyle(e.start, e.end, e.style));
  cell.setRichTextValue(richTexts.build());
  cell.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
}
```

- In this modified script, the text styles of the existing value and `formattedDate` of the adding text are set.
- As above sample, `formattedDate` has the bold and red font color.

### Answer for question 3:

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to retrieve the text styles of the existing values and also set the text style for `formattedDate`, and then, set the text styles after the value was added. "RichTextValue" is also used for this. And also, when the cell is empty, it is required to set the text style for `formattedDate` of the adding text.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
if (value === '') {
    value = value + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
    sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
    cell.setValue(value);
} else {
    value = value + "\n\n" + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
    sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
    cell.setValue(value);
}
```

To:

```
var textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor("#FF0000").build();  // Please set this for the additional text.
if (value === '') {
  value = " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
  var richTexts = SpreadsheetApp
    .newRichTextValue()
    .setText(" " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1)
    .setTextStyle((" ").length, (" " + formattedDate).length, textStyle);
  cell.setRichTextValue(richTexts.build());
  cell.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
} else {
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var existingStyles = richTextValue.getRuns().map(e => ({start: e.getStartIndex(), end: e.getEndIndex(), style: e.getTextStyle()}));
  var startOffset = (value + "\n\n" + " ").length;
  existingStyles.push({start: startOffset, end: startOffset + formattedDate.length, style: textStyle});
  var richTexts = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value + "\n\n" + "到 " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1);
  existingStyles.forEach(e => richTexts.setTextStyle(e.start, e.end, e.style));
  cell.setRichTextValue(richTexts.build());
  cell.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
}
```

### Reference:

- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Comment: Nice one! Works like a charm

Comment: Just noticed your last paragraph. Sorry for the off topic question, but is there any way to also allow some formatting for the added text as well?  For example to make the variable `formattedDate` appear in different font weight/color?

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I added one more modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, I do confirm that the second script works almost perfectly. The only tiny problem with it is that I'm still unable to add partially formatted values with the "if" part of the code, that is to say to the empty cell. If the cell contains at least one character - it works very well. 

`if (value === '') {
      value = value + " " + formattedDate + " call " + options1 + number1 + ": " + activity1;
      sheet.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
      cell.setValue(value);`

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. About your 3rd question, I added one more script by updating my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It works super well! Thank you, @Tanaike, you're a real pro!